# Are lifetimes part of the type?

Tags: rust, types, language-lawyer

The various documentation, such as [the types reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html), does not go into the relationship between types and lifetimes in detail. This made me wonder if lifetimes are part of types themselves or if they are just compiler hints that are erased before [monomorphization](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/backend/monomorph.html) occurs.

Given the following example:

```rust
fn example<'a, 'b>(a: &'a str, b: &'b str) {
    struct Foo<T> {
        t: T,
    }

    let bar = Foo { t: a };
    let baz = Foo { t: b };
}
```

Are `bar` and `baz` both of the same type with lifetimes erased (i.e. `Foo<&str>`) and sharing one monomorphized copy, or are they two distinct types `Foo<&'a str>` and `Foo<&'b str>` where the lifetime is part of the type?

And as a side note: is the type inference algorithm documented anywhere for how `T` received its final type in each case?

Comment: While `&'a str` and `&'b str`  as indeed distinct types, it is worth noting that if you add the restriction `'a: 'b` then `&'a str` is a subtype of `&'b str`. And consequently `&'static str` is a subtype of both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of different issues here. For values, *every* type is erased. Rust compiles to native, and on a native architecture, `Foo` and every other type is just a sequence of bytes. There's no reflection like in Java that can recover even a partial type.

The monomorphization issue comes up with generic functions. Specifically,

```
fn foo<T>(x: T) -> T {
  x
}
```

This function will generate a different (native) function for each `T`, so `foo(0 as i32)` and `foo("ABC")` are actually calling distinct functions. In *that* sense, lifetimes are erased before monomorphization  occurs, so if we have a function that looks like

```
fn foo<'a, T>(x: &'a T) -> &'a T {
  x
}
```

then only differing `T` parameters will result in different functions. If only the lifetimes differ, new functions will not be generated.

Comment: To sum up, are you saying that lifetimes are part of the type until monomorphization occurs then they lose their lifetime? Would you kindly provide a source if possible?

Comment: @LouisQuinn You can read about [`rustc`](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/overview.html) (the authoritative implementation that defines Rust) and how it works. In the guide, it describes that borrow checks (and therefore lifetimes) are assessed when the code is transformed into a mid-level intermediate representation (MIR) and afterwards is not considered when doing code generation. LLVM doesn't know about Rust lifetimes and references are just pointers at that point. So yes, lifetimes can be said to be compiler hints that are erased before monomorphization.